# Limit of a sequence defined by an integral

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis

Set $f(x)=\int^{\infty}_1\frac{\cos(xt)}{(t^2-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}}$ with $ x>0$.

Let $k$ be a function in $C^\infty$  with compact support contained in $\Bbb{R}_+$.

Put $$I_n=\frac{\int^{\infty}_0| k'(t)f(nt) |^2dt}{ \int^{\infty}_0| k(t)f(nt)|^2dt}$$.

Can we say that $\lim_{n\to\infty} I_n<\infty$.

Thanks

Comment: Note that $f(0)$ is undefined.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Thank you for changing the post. What have you done so far? Where does this problem come from?

Comment: This problem comes from the following question: I m looking for a sequence $(f_j)\in C^\infty(\Bbb{R})$ such that   
$$
\int^\infty_0\Big|\partial^2_r  f_j+\frac{1}{r}\partial_r f_j+r^2f_j\Big|^2rdr\to 0,
$$ and  

$$\int_{\Bbb{R^+}}|f_j(r)|^2 rdr=1\quad\forall j\in\Bbb{N}.$$

To do so I consider the equation  $\partial^2_r  f+\frac{1}{r}\partial_r f+r^2f=0$ which admits for solution the above function $f$. Then I put $f_j(x)=f(x)K(x)$ where $K$ is a function with compact support contained in $\Bbb{R}_+$ and I get the problem in question.